# Pandas DataFrame - 'pairwise' connections as new columns based on unique id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
        id  name
    0   12  molly
    1   12  james
    2   10  adam
    3   8   susan
    4   10  molly
    5   9   pete
    6   2   james
    7   10  Bob
    8   8   james
    9   2   adam
    10  12  Gary
```

I want to create 'pairwise' columns based on the id number with cols 'name_x' and 'name_y' where both names have the same id like this:

```
    id  name_x  name_y
0   12  molly   james
1   12  molly   gary
2   12  gary    james
3   10  adam    molly
4   10  adam    Bob
5   10  molly   Bob
6   8   susan   james
7   2   james   adam
```

I know there must be a solution for this somewhere but I can't think of the correct terminology to find it!

Comment: Does order matter? For example, is adam - molly different from molly - adam?

Comment: no, in this case the order doesn't matter!

Answer (score 1):

Let's use itertools.combiniations:

```
from itertools import combinations

df.groupby('id')['name']\
  .apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame((i for i in combinations(x.values,2))))\
  .reset_index().drop('level_1',axis=1)\
  .rename(columns={0:'name_x',1:'name_y'})
```

Output:

```
   id name_x name_y
0   2  james   adam
1   8  susan  james
2  10   adam  molly
3  10   adam    Bob
4  10  molly    Bob
5  12  molly  james
6  12  molly   Gary
7  12  james   Gary
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `itertools.combinations` would be the following:

```
In [30]: from itertools import combinations

In [31]: df.groupby('id').name.apply(lambda group: list(combinations(group, 2))).apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).apply(pd.Series).rename(columns={0: 'name_x', 1: 'name_y'})
Out[31]:
   name_x name_y
id
2   james   adam
8   susan  james
10   adam  molly
10   adam    Bob
10  molly    Bob
12  molly  james
12  molly   Gary
12  james   Gary
```